# ChartboostX not loading more apps

Tags: cocos2d-x, chartboost

I am using this wrapper someone recommended for my iOS cocos2dx game [link](https://github.com/wenbin1989/Chartboost-x). It works when I call the `showInterstitial()` method, but when I try to use the `showMoreApps` the dialog appears for a split second and then disappears.

In my AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() I do this

```
ChartboostX::sharedChartboostX()->setAppId("REDACTED");
ChartboostX::sharedChartboostX()->setAppSignature("REDACTED");
ChartboostX::sharedChartboostX()->startSession();
ChartboostX::sharedChartboostX()->cacheMoreApps();
```

And then when I want to call the showMoreApps I do this

```
ChartboostX::sharedChartboostX()->showMoreApps();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my wrapper for Chartboost. It has been updated to use the latest version of the Chartboost SDK and works perfectly in my cocos2D-x game. I have not finished the android documentation yet but you can probably work it out yourself if you need to. The documentation for iOS is almost finished and quite easy to follow.(FYI the class ADELLE is the chartboost delegate and is an objective C++ class so you can use C++ in it as you normally would mixed in with the objective C. This is the same for AdWrapper.mm)

Check it out and see if it works for you.
https://github.com/Lochlanna/Chartboost-Cocos2D-x